# XSS filtering on CodeIgniter form

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am currently learning the framework "CodeIgniter". But I have a problem for my Form validation. First, let me show you my view :

```
<form method="post" action="connexion">
  <label for="pseudo">Pseudo : </label>
  <input type="text" name="pseudo" value="" />

  <label for="mdp">Mot de passe :</label>
  <input type="password" name="mdp" value="" />

  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></form>
```

My controller :

```
public function connexion()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pseudo', '"user name"', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mdp',    '"password"',       'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $this->load->view('connexion_ok');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
}
```

When I remove the "xss_clean" filter in my controller in the set_rules(), it works perfectly, the form is valid. If the "xss_clean" is present, it doesn't work, it goes in the else. I don't use special chars in my input, only letters.

In the settings I put this on true : $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

I read somewhere the "xss_clean" filter is useless. What else can I use ? Maybe helpers or something else ?
Thank you

Comment: The validation ! It goes in the else

Comment: XSS Protection functionality is turned off by default. To turn on this functionality, you simply either set the global configuration (i.e. system/application/config/config.php) as `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` You don't need or want this on all the time. This config setting is officially deprecated. It will likely disapear in the future.

Second, if you are using version 3.0.x then remove ‘xss_clean’ from your validation rules. It is not on the officially supported [list of form validation rules](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference).

The place where you can employ XSS filtering is when using the [Input Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) to fetch data from POST, GET, COOKIE or SERVER. Most of the input methods have a second param that enables running the data through `xss_clean()`. Example: `$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE);` Will get the value of `$_POST['some_data']`and run it through `xss_clean()`. If the second param is FALSE (or omitted) `xss_clean()` will not be used.

Answer (score 5):

I don't agree with DFriend's answer.

Per [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#xss-filtering):

> XSS escaping should be performed on output, not input!

So the solution he proposed would actually do the same of the deprecated global configuration `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`, with the difference of adding much more code and manual work to add an extra bollean parameter for each `$this->input->post`.

The proper way is to use the `set_value` on your views:

`<input type="password" name="mdp" value="<?=set_value('mdp')?>" />`

[This function filters XSS vulnerabilities by default:](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value)

> set_value($field[, $default = ''[, $html_escape = TRUE]])

Comment: I agree. XSS escaping should be performed on output, not input. But the question was about why validation was failing not about when to perform XSS escaping. Every web developer should read and follow the recommendations found on the [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) webpage.